# What does お使いになられた mean

Tags: meaning

So in this game there is a line about how some object is called a dragon egg and inside it seems there are these magic items that god placed inside.  The part of the sentence that I do not get is お使いになられた.  お使い is a messenger and なられた is the passive form of なる.  It sounds like the magic items became the messenger.  Maybe I am misunderstanding the use of the passive verb here.  Could someone clarify that section this to me?

> あれは竜の卵と呼ばれるもので中に神さまが**お使いになられた**魔法の品が入っておるそうな。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you are overanalyzing the phrase.

「お使いになられた」 here is simply the ***honorific*** form of the past-tense verb 「使った」("used") -- nothing more, nothing less.  It is 100% in the ***active*** voice.  The honorific form is used because the subject of the verb is God.

「お使い」 does not mean a "messenger" here, either.  It is the ***honorific noun form*** of the verb 「使う」.  "The act of using (something)", that is.

You will need to learn the common honorific verb form:

> 「お/ご + Noun + になる」

See here for more examples:

[Verbs which are more frequently used to built the honorific passive forms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11533/verbs-which-are-more-frequently-used-to-built-the-honorific-passive-forms/11539#11539)

> "That is called the Drangon's Egg and it is said to contain within it the magical items that God used."